# Django DRF filter and update only runs on server reboot

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    first_name = encrypt(models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False))
    last_name = encrypt(models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=False))
    email = encrypt(models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True))
    ...
    application_status = models.ForeignKey(
        ApplicationStatus,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="applicant_application_status",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    ) 
    objects = models.Manager()
    mask = MaskApplicantManager()
```

With this custom manager:

```
class MaskedQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def mask_applicants(self):
        return self.exclude(application_status__status="Hired").update(
            first_name="Masked", last_name="Masked", email="masked@mail.com"
    )


class MaskApplicantManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MaskedQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def mask_applicants(self):
        return self.get_queryset().mask_applicants()
```

What is the best approach for adding this to a generic view? Currently tried this:

```
class AppliedListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ApplicantSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = Set10Pagination
    lookup_url_kwarg = "job_vacancy"

    def get_queryset(self):
        vacancy = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        applicant = Applicant.mask.filter(job_vacancy=vacancy).order_by("-id")
        return applicant
```

Although the masked details never run, if I change applicant to:

```
applicant = Applicant.mask.mask_applicants().filter(job_vacancy=vacancy).order_by("-id")
```

Then the error below is returned but on dev server reboot the masked details are applied:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Would a class method or custom django-admin command be a better option?

Comment: This is because you are updating while fetching querysets and update return integer response that tells you how many instances has been updated.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal The intention is to mask the applicant details of all other applicants if a single applicant_status is set to "Hired" although I realise I'm not using the correct approach. The ListAPIView is returning a list only for the vacancy applied for, do you believe a class method would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `update` in `mask_applicants`

```
def mask_applicants(self):
        return self.exclude(application_status__status="Hired")
```

As update returns `integer` and `integer` has no attribute `filter`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a custom django-admin management command:

```
from applicant.models import Applicant
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
help = "Mask applicants"

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument("vacancy_id", nargs="+", type=int, help="Vacancy ID")

def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    vacancy_ids = kwargs["vacancy_id"]

    for vacancy_id in vacancy_ids:
        try:
            applicant = (
                Applicant.objects.exclude(application_status__status="Hired")
                .filter(job_vacancy__exact=vacancy_id)
                .update(
                    first_name="Masked",
                    last_name="Masked",
                    email="masked@mail.com",
                )
            )
            self.stdout.write(
                self.style.SUCCESS(
                    "Applicant masked count=%s Vacancy ID:(%s) updated successfully!"
                    % (applicant, vacancy_id)
                )
            )
        except vacancy_id.ValueError:
            self.stdout.write(
                self.style.WARNING('Vacancy ID:"%s" does not exist.' % vacancy_id)
            )
```

Then run:

```
python manage.py mask_applicants_cmd 64
```

Or multiple ID's with:

```
 python manage.py mask_applicants_cmd 64 72 84
```